# Convert struct with dynamic arrays to double pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I had a data structure, which contain some dynamic sized fields.
I.e. `void *methods[0]` I also declared them as `void *methods[]`, but this seems also wrong, because this shouldn't be the only field in the struct.

This structure is only to read memory which is defined somewhere else, so I can't just add the size of methods inside itable_t/itt_t and define methods/entries as dynamic.

The code below works, but give me some warnings which I don't want.

```
struct itable_t {
    void *methods[0];
};
typedef struct itable_t itable_t;


struct itt_entry_t {
    itable_t *itable;
    void     *id;
    int32_t   prev;
    int32_t   next;
};
typedef struct itt_entry_t itt_entry_t;


struct itt_t {
    itt_entry_t entries[0];
};
typedef struct itt_t itt_t;


struct vtable_t {
    rtti_t *rtti;
    itt_t  *itt;
    void   *dynamic_methods[];
};
typedef struct vtable_t vtable_t;

struct object_t {
    vtable_t *vptr;
};
typedef struct object_t object_t;
```

So I tried to translate the structure to the following, which doesn't seems to be correct, because I get some segmentation faults

```
struct itt_entry_t {
    void    **itable;
    void     *id;
    int32_t   prev;
    int32_t   next;
};
typedef struct itt_entry_t itt_entry_t;


struct vtable_t {
    rtti_t        *rtti;
    itt_entry_t  **itt;
    void          *dynamic_methods[];
};
typedef struct vtable_t vtable_t;

struct object_t {
    vtable_t *vptr;
};
typedef struct object_t object_t;
```

How should I define and access my structs, so that they work?

---

EDIT: How the structure is currently used:
The function is called from assembler

```
movl %edi, (%esp)
movl $itable_table_name_815, 4(%esp)
movl $0x4, 8(%esp)
call oo_searched_itable_method
```

c function

```
void *oo_searched_itable_method(const object_t *obj, void *interface_id, int32_t offset)
{
    itt_t *itt = obj->vptr->itt;

    int32_t i = 1;
    do {
        if (itt->entries[i].id == interface_id) {
            return itt->entries[i].itable->methods[offset];
        }
    }
    while (itt->entries[++i].id != NULL);

    // should never happen
    abort();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose (as you think) of array with size 0? Because once you define a static array with specific size (0 in your case) it won't be able to change! This is static! So defining an array of size 0 is meaningless.

Comment: The size isn't zero, I just don't know the size at compile time. The structure represents memory which is created somewhere else

Comment: Are you want to use itable_t.methods as function pointer?

Comment: A *dynamic sized array* may of course exist as the last element of a struct. The problem is that the **actual size** of the structure is different (and greater) than the *declared* size known by the compiler, so you cannot use an array of such structures. I can (more or less) understand how the first code works, but I cannot understand how you use the translated code.

Comment: This isn't valid C code. Please post which compiler you are using and which non-standard extensions that are enabled.

Comment: @Philipp "The size isn't zero" - it is not true. You are creating a static array with fixed size of 0: `void *methods[0];` (and things like `void   *dynamic_methods[];` are illegal) if you want to create it somewhere else it should be dynamic, not static and this is the way to define it: `void** methods;` then when you know that `size` of it you should allocate it `methods = malloc(size*sizeof(void*));` Now `methods` can be treated as an array of `void*` of size `size`.

Comment: You _can't_ create arrays of size zero in C, they are explicitly banned by the standard. This is non-standard code. You would have to use _flexible array members_ such as `void *dynamic_methods[]`, which in turn requires C99, or otherwise they are not supported and invoke undefined behavior. The whole code seems quite confused with how the C language works in general. All those pointer-to-pointer are most likely nonsense: a pointer to pointer is not an array, it is not a 2D array, it cannot be used to point at an array and it cannot be used to point at a 2D array.

Comment: I added some more information - hope that helps for better understanding

Comment: @Phillip: look at Alex's comment. This is how it's done.

Comment: No don't look at that comment... (wish you could down vote comments). The OP should declare a flexible array member and for more than one dimension he should declare array pointers. Never declare icky pointer-to-pointer lookup tables fragmented all over the heap, that is 100% bad advise in any given scenario. It is still not clear to me what the code is supposed to do, so I'll refrain from posting an answer.

Comment: I cant use flexible array member, because `struct itable_t { void *methods[]; }` is forbidden as there is no first entry with it's size. The data is  created somewhere else and I cant change it

Comment: First, you should not use `void *` anyway. Use the correct target type, unless you hate your compiler ("real men don't use automatic typechecking"). Why is a flexible array member "forbidden"? As @Lundin states, this is the way to go. Actually, a zero-length array is forbidden.

Comment: Because a flexible array need at least a struct with two members - one which defines the length and the other for the flexible array. But as the structure isn't defined by me, I can't add a length as the first element

Comment: A flexible array member `void *methods[]` alone in a struct with no other members makes no sense. You should just use a pointer to pointer `void**`, instead. This would give you exactly the thing that you seem to want, access to a table of `void*` of unknown length.

Comment: I found a solution - thanks for your help. Posted an answer with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now with the following code - thanks for any help and good suggestions I got in the comments.

structure definition:

```
struct itt_entry_t {
    void    **itable;
    void     *id;
    int32_t   prev;
    int32_t   next;
};
typedef struct itt_entry_t itt_entry_t;


struct vtable_t {
    rtti_t        *rtti;
    itt_entry_t   *itt;
    void          *dynamic_methods[];
};
typedef struct vtable_t vtable_t;

struct object_t {
    vtable_t *vptr;
};
typedef struct object_t object_t;
```

code which uses the structurs

```
void *oo_searched_itable_method(const object_t *obj, void *interface_id, int32_t offset) {
    itt_entry_t *itt = obj->vptr->itt;

    int32_t i = 1;
    do {
        if (itt[i].id == interface_id) {
            return itt[i].itable[offset];
        }
    }
    while (itt[++i].id != NULL);


    fprintf(stderr, "ITable not found...");
    abort();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to me, i declare structures like that :

```
typedef struct s_data
{
     char *str;
     int  foo;
}             t_data;
```

Now in your code you need to declare it by this way :

```
t_data my_struct;

my_struct.foo = 8;
my_struct.str = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
my_struct.str = strcpy(my_struct.str, "foobar");
```

But i need more informations from you, what are the warnings and show me how you declare and access your structure.

Comment: If you declare a `void *foobar` you need to malloc it, you know that don't you ?

Comment: better write `my_struct.str = malloc(4 * sizeof *my_struct.str);` but you can drop the `sizeof` anyway: `my_struct.str = malloc(4);` (sizeof char is 1), but more importantly: `strcpy(my_struct.str, "foobar");` will overflow: `foobar` needs `malloc(7)` or more. The simplest way to assign a string to a pointer in this case, though, would be to write `my_struct.str = strdup("foobar");`

Comment: Yes sorry the 4 in the malloc was an example